# Failed to construct 'RTCPeerConnection': Unsatisfiable constraint IceTransports

Tags: webrtc, restcomm

I trying to setup RestComm Web SDK demo application on my local system, I just want to create an application for audio/video, chat, IVR, etc(RestComm provide me perfect solution for my needs). Now I have setup RestComm Web SDK on my local system and whenever I an trying to sip call, It throws **WebRTCommClient:call(): catched exception:NotSupportedError: Failed to construct 'RTCPeerConnection': Unsatisfiable constraint IceTransports** on browser console.

**My webRTC confrigration is as below:**

```
// setup WebRTClient
            wrtcConfiguration = {
                communicationMode: WebRTCommClient.prototype.SIP,
                sip: {
                    sipUserAgent: 'TelScale RestComm Web Client 1.0.0 BETA4',
                    sipRegisterMode: register,
                    sipOutboundProxy: parameters['registrar'],
                    sipDomain: parameters['domain'],
                    sipDisplayName: parameters['username'],
                    sipUserName: parameters['username'],
                    sipLogin: parameters['username'],
                    sipPassword: parameters['password'],
                },
                RTCPeerConnection: {
                    iceServers: undefined,
                    stunServer: 'stun.l.google.com:19302',
                    turnServer: undefined,
                    turnLogin: undefined,
                    turnPassword: undefined,
                }
            };
```

While I can use **olympus** without any issue in Chrome Browser. I am stuck with this exception, any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem here is that the version of Webrtcomm library inside the demo application you are using is outdated and doesn't include a fix for latest Chrome version. So please replace samples/hello-world/scripts/WebRTComm.js within your repository, with:

https://github.com/RestComm/webrtcomm/blob/master/build/WebRTComm.js

That should fix your issue.

Best regards,
Antonis Tsakiridis